# Deploying a netbeans java ee project into openshift

Tags: git, maven, netbeans, openshift

I have a Netbeans java ee project with Wildfly server. It works OK locally (on my laptop, deployed as localhost:8080/myserver/login)

However I want to upload it into the openshift cloud.
My project structure is not Maven like but the original netbeans with web.xml inside WEB-INF etc

Is it necessary to convert my project into a Maven project before I upload it into openshift and use all these Git procedures?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly how you would like to deploy your project (either using git, or by deploying a WAR/EAR file), you can refer to this page of the Developer Portal: https://developers.openshift.com/servers/jbossas/deployment-options.html

If you are using another application server besides JBossAS, you can find instructions for them in the Developer Portal also under these sections: https://developers.openshift.com/servers/